# How does NSFetchRequest know which managed object context is in scope?

Tags: ios, macos, core-data

When calling `execute()` on an `NSFetchRequest`, you'll get an error if the fetch request doesn't know about an `NSManagedObjectContext`. One way to provide that context is call `execute` in a block that is passed to `managedObjectContext.perform()`.

Somehow the fetch request is able to determine what the context is. I assume it must be looking at a thread-local variable somewhere. I would like to use this mechanism for my own nefarious purposes, but for the life of me I can't figure out where this context is stored.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your Core Data Stack look like, you may be able to obtain it there.

Answer (score 0):

It's undocumented, relying on private API.

When you create a managed object context, you specify either `.mainQueueConcurrencyType` or `.privateQueueConcurrencyType`. This tells the context what kind of queue to use, either the main queue or a private dispatch queue.

When you `execute()` a fetch request, it executes using "...the managed object context that is associated with the current queue." That's the queue the context was created with, either main or private.

How does it know which queue? It's undocumented, relying on some internal means not exposed to developers outside of Apple. Most likely it asks `DispatchQueue` for the current queue (undocumented) and then finds the context via queue-specific data. You might discover something about this by looking at the current queue while debugging the code (there's no API to get it but the debugger knows). From there you might find the context by using `DispatchQueue` methods, maybe `getSpecific<T>(key: DispatchSpecificKey<T>)`.

But that's a lot of "might" and "maybe" and it's nothing you'll find via documented APIs.